# Disabling repetitive logs for a given logger

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback

Can anyone suggest if there is a way to disable the repetitive logs from the below specific class name or logger name.

I found an example of disabling the total logs for given logger name.

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper" level="OFF"/>
```

What if I would like to log in this error but only once, for example, 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Please check a [DuplicateMessageFilter](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#DuplicateMessageFilter) in Logback.